# Day names in column Y based on Dates in a column X

Tags: arrays, date, if-statement, google-sheets, string-formatting

So, I populate my column D with dates from column B with this formula placed in D1.

```
=QUERY(B2:B;"SELECT * where B is not null";-1)
```

I can't figure out how to populate column E with day names based on dates in column B, with a single formula in cell E1.

I know I could use

```
=TEXT(B2;"DDDD")
```

and then copy that formula in every cell of column E, but I guess there's a better solution which solves the issue with formula in single cell. ;)

I'm guessing the solution is something with ARRAYFORMULA and/or QUERY and TEXT but I don't know how to combine those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;TEXT(B2:B; "DDDD")))
```